# Create a Generic type interface with some specific interface

Tags: typescript

I don't really know the terms to search on google for this, so it might be duplicated.

I have an interface that looks like

```
export interface SolidOptions<T>  {
  position: Cartesian3;
  options?: T;
}
```

now, I want this T to be *ONLY* of 3 types : CylinderOptions | RectangleOptions | PolygoneOptions

I do *NOT* want this solution :

```
export interface SolidOptions<T>  {
  position: Cesium.Cartesian3;
  options?: CylinderOptions | RectangleOptions | PolygoneOptions;
}
```

the reason why is I want to use this as follow :

```
    static generateCylinder = (options: SolidOptions<CylinderOptions>)=>  {
    }
    
    static generateRectangle = (options: SolidOptions<RectangleOptions >)=>  {
    }

    static generatePolygon = (options: SolidOptions<PolygoneOptions>)=>  {
    }
```

and not having the abilities to pass the wrong type to the wrong function.

Answer (score 3):

You can define [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) on generic type parameter:

```
export interface SolidOptions<T extends CylinderOptions | RectangleOptions | PolygoneOptions> {
  position: Cartesian3;
  options?: T;
}
```

Comment: Actually I knew it, but it was triggering me that I could pass anything to it.
But yes in the end, if I ignore the other properties it doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: You would only be able to pass the provided values in the extends - any values which matches those types.  If those types are too general then it may allow more than you'd like.